# Is this code threadsafe or why am I concern with Url.Helper

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, thread-safety

Say that I have

```
public static class M
{
    public static string Concat(string a, string b)
    {
        return N.AddOne(a, b);
    }
    public static string Concat2(string a, string b)
    {
        return SomeThreadSafeMethod(a, b);
    }
}

public static class N
{
 public static string AddOne(string a, string b)
    {
        return a+b+1;
    }
}
```

Is M.Concat a threadsafe operation? 
What about M.Concat2? Would it be possible for SomeThreadSafeMethod get call with a different a or b in a multithread context?

The reason I ask this question is I want to have a better understanding of how C# deal with threading, especially 
for the M.Concat2 case.

Secondly I am working with Asp.net MVC and I am concern that when I call Html.ActionLink or RouteLink with a route with variable
something simple such as

```
Html.ActionLink("Test", "Index", "Test", new { Model.Id, Model.State})
```

When multiple users hitting the same page, each of them will get a different State. If it's not threadsafe then I might get back a different route than intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Concat` method is absolutely thread safe because it doesn't set any variable. The `Concat2` is also thread safe because of the way you are calling it. You only pass `Model` properties and and you get a different model instance every time. The only issue might be in the `SomeThreadSafeMethod` method if it sets static variables without locking.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, *your* code is perfectly thread-safe and [reentrant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_(subroutine)).